# Akka Persistence: No Sufficient Working Example for JDBC MySQL

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

I have been trying to get my EventSourceBehavior to write to MySQL and am getting following error, what could be the issue? Error is very generic and it is hard to see what is the root cause. Is there a way to test wether my JDBC is correctly configured via Akka, ex connectivity etc, Thanks

```
2020-11-20 00:48:57,999 WAR HikariConfig              slick.db - using dataSourceClassName and ignoring jdbcUrl.
2020-11-20 00:48:57,999 WAR HikariConfig              slick.db - using dataSourceClassName and ignoring jdbcUrl.
2020-11-20 00:48:58,002 INF HikariDataSource          slick.db - Starting...
2020-11-20 00:48:58,002 INF HikariDataSource          slick.db - Starting...
2020-11-20 00:48:58,041 INF HikariDataSource          slick.db - Start completed.
2020-11-20 00:48:58,042 INF HikariDataSource          slick.db - Start completed.
2020-11-20 00:49:18,293 ERR Main$                     Supervisor StopSupervisor saw failure: Exception during recovery from snapshot. PersistenceId [first]. Circuit Breaker Timed out.
akka.persistence.typed.internal.JournalFailureException: Exception during recovery from snapshot. PersistenceId [first]. Circuit Breaker Timed out.
```

application.conf

```
akka {
  loglevel = DEBUG

  persistence {
    journal.plugin = "jdbc-journal"
    snapshot-store.plugin = "jdbc-snapshot-store"
  }
}

slick {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  db {
    dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource"
    driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
    user = nilu
    password = "password"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, with Akka Persistence JDBC, you'll need to specify the database to use, not just the DBMS (server) to connect to.  So if the DB was called `my_akka_persistence`, the JDBC URL would be something like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_akka_persistence`.

Comment: That too, but I had to also set host and ports separately, url was not enough for some reason.